# Big Sur Safari doesn't update passwords in iCloud Keychain

Tags: icloud, safari, keychain

[Update] This is intermittent . Sometimes does, sometimes doesn't.

Safari will not update the password in iCloud Keychain or create a new date stamped edition of the password even though it reports that it is saved.

I have to delete the current password in the Keychain first, to have the new password saved otherwise next time I log in, the old version of the password is used.

This appears to be the case with all devices sharing the iCloud Keychain: Mac, iPad, iPhone although editing the keychain only possible in macOS

- macOS Big Sur 11.1
- iPadOS and iOS latest
- I am logged into my Apple ID
- I have selected to use Keychain on iCloud as I have done for several OS versions